# Assigning the i as a different var for each loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist, fetch-api

Current bootcamp student here. I am fetching an API four different times with a for loop. However, to get to the data I want per loop, I need to use the name of that index to navigate the array and innerText to my HTMl. Is there a way to do this? I am trying to change the text of (#"coin" + i + "price") located at the end of the javascript code. If you need me to clarify some things up or add in more information to aid in this problem please let me know. Thanks in advance.

(Edit) The for loop grabs four random Cryptocurrency indexes from another api call

```
<!-- Upper Cards -->
      <div class="flex bg-transparent p-8 justify-between">
        <!-- Upper Left Card -->
        <div class="bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-xl p-8 topleft">
          <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">
            <button
              class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-14 h-14 text-blue-100 bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-400 to-yellow-500 rounded-full"
            >
              <svg
                fill="#FFFFFF"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                class="h-8 w-8"
                viewBox="0 0 26 26"
                width="26px"
                height="26px"
              >
                <path
                  d="M 9 5 L 9 7 L 7 7 L 7 20 L 9 20 L 9 22 L 11 22 L 11 20 L 13 20 L 13 22 L 15 22 L 15 19.90625 C 15.265625 19.871094 15.554688 19.855469 15.8125 19.8125 C 16.414063 19.613281 16.90625 19.394531 17.40625 19.09375 C 17.804688 18.792969 18.199219 18.40625 18.5 17.90625 C 18.800781 17.40625 18.90625 16.886719 18.90625 16.1875 C 18.90625 15.386719 18.585938 14.695313 18.1875 14.09375 C 17.6875 13.492188 17.085938 13.105469 16.1875 12.90625 C 16.886719 12.605469 17.386719 12.210938 17.6875 11.8125 C 17.988281 11.414063 18.1875 10.886719 18.1875 10.1875 C 18.1875 9.585938 18.105469 9.085938 17.90625 8.6875 C 17.707031 8.289063 17.398438 7.886719 17 7.6875 C 16.601563 7.488281 16.195313 7.289063 15.59375 7.1875 C 15.398438 7.15625 15.199219 7.125 15 7.09375 L 15 5 L 13 5 L 13 7 L 11 7 L 11 5 Z M 10 9 L 12.90625 9 C 13.207031 9 13.488281 8.992188 13.6875 9.09375 C 13.988281 9.09375 14.207031 9.210938 14.40625 9.3125 C 14.605469 9.414063 14.804688 9.488281 14.90625 9.6875 C 15.007813 9.886719 15.09375 10.105469 15.09375 10.40625 C 15.09375 11.007813 14.992188 11.394531 14.59375 11.59375 C 14.195313 11.894531 13.789063 12 13.1875 12 L 10 12 Z M 10 14 L 13.5 14 C 14.199219 14 14.8125 14.199219 15.3125 14.5 C 15.8125 14.800781 16 15.394531 16 16.09375 C 16 16.394531 15.914063 16.800781 15.8125 17 C 15.613281 17.300781 15.386719 17.492188 15.1875 17.59375 C 14.988281 17.695313 14.707031 17.804688 14.40625 17.90625 C 14.105469 18.007813 13.707031 18 13.40625 18 L 10 18 Z"
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div>
              <span class="font-bold text-green-500 padding-left"
                >+ $726 (15%)</span
              ><br />
              <span class="font-bold text-black-500 Mid padding-left"
                >New Element</span
              ><br />
              <span class="font-medium text-xs text-gray-500 flex justify-end"
                >0.382 coin</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-sm text-gray-400" id="coin1name">
              BTC
            </h3>
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-700" id="coin1price">
              Coin 1
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Upper Right Card -->
        <div class="bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-xl p-8 topright">
          <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">
            <button
              class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-14 h-14 text-blue-100 bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-400 to-yellow-500 rounded-full"
            >
              <svg
                fill="#FFFFFF"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                class="h-8 w-8"
                viewBox="0 0 26 26"
                width="26px"
                height="26px"
              >
                <path
                  d="M 9 5 L 9 7 L 7 7 L 7 20 L 9 20 L 9 22 L 11 22 L 11 20 L 13 20 L 13 22 L 15 22 L 15 19.90625 C 15.265625 19.871094 15.554688 19.855469 15.8125 19.8125 C 16.414063 19.613281 16.90625 19.394531 17.40625 19.09375 C 17.804688 18.792969 18.199219 18.40625 18.5 17.90625 C 18.800781 17.40625 18.90625 16.886719 18.90625 16.1875 C 18.90625 15.386719 18.585938 14.695313 18.1875 14.09375 C 17.6875 13.492188 17.085938 13.105469 16.1875 12.90625 C 16.886719 12.605469 17.386719 12.210938 17.6875 11.8125 C 17.988281 11.414063 18.1875 10.886719 18.1875 10.1875 C 18.1875 9.585938 18.105469 9.085938 17.90625 8.6875 C 17.707031 8.289063 17.398438 7.886719 17 7.6875 C 16.601563 7.488281 16.195313 7.289063 15.59375 7.1875 C 15.398438 7.15625 15.199219 7.125 15 7.09375 L 15 5 L 13 5 L 13 7 L 11 7 L 11 5 Z M 10 9 L 12.90625 9 C 13.207031 9 13.488281 8.992188 13.6875 9.09375 C 13.988281 9.09375 14.207031 9.210938 14.40625 9.3125 C 14.605469 9.414063 14.804688 9.488281 14.90625 9.6875 C 15.007813 9.886719 15.09375 10.105469 15.09375 10.40625 C 15.09375 11.007813 14.992188 11.394531 14.59375 11.59375 C 14.195313 11.894531 13.789063 12 13.1875 12 L 10 12 Z M 10 14 L 13.5 14 C 14.199219 14 14.8125 14.199219 15.3125 14.5 C 15.8125 14.800781 16 15.394531 16 16.09375 C 16 16.394531 15.914063 16.800781 15.8125 17 C 15.613281 17.300781 15.386719 17.492188 15.1875 17.59375 C 14.988281 17.695313 14.707031 17.804688 14.40625 17.90625 C 14.105469 18.007813 13.707031 18 13.40625 18 L 10 18 Z"
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div>
              <span class="font-bold text-green-500 padding-left"
                >+ $726 (15%)</span
              ><br />
              <span class="font-bold text-black-500 Mid padding-left"
                >New Element</span
              ><br />
              <span class="font-medium text-xs text-gray-500 flex justify-end"
                >0.382 coin</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-sm text-gray-400" id="coin2name">
              BTC
            </h3>
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-700" id="coin2price">
              Coin 2
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
function getRandomApi() {
  let randomApiUrl = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/blockchain/list?api_key=850252ca876085a93a414bceb298e21862313b438417b87364eb0fe9aab45e1c`;
  fetch(randomApiUrl)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        updatePrice(data, i);
      }
    });
}
let updatePrice = function (randomData, i) {
  let keys = Object.keys(randomData.Data);
  console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length));
  let propertyName = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
  console.log(propertyName);
  let symbolName = randomData.Data[propertyName].symbol;
  console.log(symbolName);
  fetch(
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=${symbolName}&tsyms=USD`
  )
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector("#coin" + i + "price").innerText = data.DISPLAY.symbolName.USD.PRICE;
      document.querySelector("#coin" + i + "name").innerText = symbolName;
    });
};
```

[image][image][image: Error Image]

Comment: What problem are you having?  What does `console.log("#coin" + i + "name")` display?  Is there an error?

Comment: @James so I can't seem to get the proper data to show up. If I set the innerText to data.DISPLAY.symbolName.USD.PRICE, an error pops up. I have just now added the error screenshot to the question.

Comment: This `data.DISPLAY.symbolName.USD.PRICE` wont take the value of `symbolName` but rather the name of it. You probably want `data.DISPLAY[symbolName].USD.PRICE`